# Make a datetime countdown timer in rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, datetime, timer

Hello Im so close to making this datetime counter. Im assuming because im using `date` `new Date` in my code that im not getting the code to work? Am i suppose to be using `date` `datetime` `time`? When i make a `puts "#{reservation.due_date}" I get the right duedate so im confused why the counter is not working.

```html
 

<div id="dueDate-counter">
   <table>
     <tr>
      <td>days</td>
      <td>hrs</td>
      <td>mns</td>
      <td>secs</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td id="days"></td>
      <td id="hours"></td>
      <td id="minutes"></td>
      <td id="seconds"></td>
     </tr>
            
    </table> 

     <script type="text/javascript">
      function countdown() {
       var now = new Date();
       var eventDate = new Date(<%= reservation.due_date %>);
       <%= puts "here is reservation !!!!!!!" %>;
       <%= puts "#{reservation.due_date}" %>;
       var currentTime = now.getTime();
       var eventTime = eventDate.getTime();

       var remTime = eventTime - currentTime;

       var s = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
       var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
       var h = Math.floor(m / 60);
       var d = Math.floor(h / 24);

       h %= 24;
       m %= 60;
       s %= 60;

       h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
       m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
       s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

       document.getElementById("days").textContent = d;
       document.getElementById("days").innerText = d;

       document.getElementById("hours").textContent = h;
       document.getElementById("minutes").textContent = m;
       document.getElementById("seconds").textContent = s;

        setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
            }

            countdown();

           </script>
           
          </div>
```

im getting blank data to show up in the `days` `hours` `etc` when viewing the page. down near the beginning of the `script` I added `eventDate` I put the `due_date` in as a new date.. now remember Its a DateTime format so it has hour minutes seconds in the database. So is this not reading because i made it `new Date` is there one for `datetime`?? thank you!!

The reservation.due_date shows up in the db as example: `2017-02-09 00:02:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need wrap an output of due date with quote

```
var eventDate = new Date("<%= reservation.due_date %>");
```

If you don't, you will get this error on your console browser

`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`